# FileHelpers.ConvertException

Tags: c#, csv, datetime, filehelpers

This is my first time using filehelpers, I have a csv that has a date column like this:

```
8/28/2015 12:00:00 AM
12/28/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

I followed the startguide on filehelpers to read the csv but get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'FileHelpers.ConvertException' occurred in FileHelpers.dll

Additional information:

> Error Converting '8/28/2015 12:00:00 AM' to type: 'DateTime'.  Using the format: 'm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss TT'

I have tried many suggestions but nothing works.

This is my definition in the class for the datetime field:

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "m/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss TT")]
public DateTime PDAte;
```

This is how I am trying to call it:

```
Console.WriteLine(peakdatapoint.PDAte.ToString("m/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss TT"));
```

Please help, I have been trying this for two days.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

See [MSDN's page for Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). You have used `m` for month when you should have used `M`.

Try this

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss TT")]
public DateTime PDAte;
```

Note: Generally, "yyyy/MM/dd" is preferred for sorting and month-day ambiguity reasons.

Comment: Also, usually people would use MM rather than just M to ensure sort orders.

Comment: @netniV me too, but the op's example shows 8/28/2015 in the csv. I will make a note in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i could parse using this  below
M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt

if i gave TT capital it was giving me the same error
pls try this M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")]

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowLessChars)]
public class A
{

[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")]
[FieldFixedLength(22)]
private DateTime mAONE;

public DateTime AONE
{
   get { return mAONE; }
   set { mAONE = value; }
}
```